# Python opencv cannot write video

Tags: python, opencv

My script cannot create an mp4 file correctly. When my `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')` and video is '.mp4', it creates an mp4 file but it is 0 KB. But when I use `*'MPJG'` to encode `.avi`, it works right.
Here is the code:

```py
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
    video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(video_path,fourcc,30,(width,height))
    for frame in frames:
        video_writer.write(frame)
    video_writer.release()
```

I tried to download the ffmpeg, but it doesn't work.
I tried to change the fourcc, as I mentioned above, it can generate an avi file correctly

Comment: `print(cv.getBuildInformation())`, check video I/O section. -- MJPG in .AVI always works because it's built into opencv -- opencv does not use arbitrary ffmpegs that are installed on your system. it uses the one it was *built with*.

Answer (score -1):

The issue must be related to the codec or the installation of necessary libraries, let me give you some steps to resolve this:

1. Ensure that FFmpeg is correctly installed on your system and that it is available in your system's PATH. OpenCV uses FFmpeg for video writing, and the absence or misconfiguration of FFmpeg can cause issues.
2. Try different fourcc codes for the MP4 format. Commonly used ones include 'XVID', 'H264'. You can experiment with these to see if any of them work for your case.

```py
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(video_path, fourcc, 30, (width, height))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it didn't work. FFmpeg is available in my PATH, and I've tried `'XVID'` and `'H264'`, the output mp4 file is still 0KB.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).